# Why are not all recursive languages undecidable?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, undecidability, decision-problem, semi-decidability

I learned that recursive language are  decidable; correct me if I am wrong. However, I have found some arguments that seem to contradict this. These may or may not be correct; please let me know.

If a language is an REL (recursive enumerable language), I know that there exists a TM (Turing machine) that accepts it (regardless of the TM halting or not). Say, however, that for a language $L$ you have found a TM which accepts it, thus indicating $L$ is REL. We know that, given a TM, it is undecidable whether the TM halts or not. Thus, it is not possible to deduce whether $L$ is recursive or not: we have a TM that accepts $L$, but whether the TM halts or not is undecidable and, thus, we cannot comment on whether $L$ is recursive or not; this makes telling whether $L$ is recursive or not *undecidable*. Hence, recursive languages should be undecidable―which they are not!

What is wrong with the above reasoning?

Comment: "Recursive" and "decidable" mean exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. The *problem* of deciding "$L$ is a recursively enumerable language" is undecidable. However, that does not make $L$ itself undecidable.

Do not mistake a language for its class! Telling whether $L$ is in a class is definitely **not** the same as deciding membership in $L$.

Comment: i still dont understand why REL are undecidable ?. given a language we can decide whether the language is decidable that the language is REL by making a TM but we cannnot deduce that the language is recursive or REL-but not recursive which makes them undecidable. also everybody knows that the memebership for recursive is decidable

Comment: tell  me one thing , that when we say that recursive language are decidable ,are we talking about the memebership problem of the language or are we concerned about that the language is itself reursive or not

Comment: @rajendra Being "decidable" (or "recursive"; they are synonyms) is a characteristic of the language itself; hence, the latter version is what is meant. This also applies to the problem of deciding whether a language is recursively enumerable or not, which is also a language.

Comment: now you try to got my point , now tell me given a language how you are going to tell whether the language is recursive ( as said by you that recursive language is decidable and offcourse we are not talking about the membership problem) or not . as you said this is decidable so i just want to know how you get to that point .

Comment: i also request you to edit your answer as it  does not convey the answer fully. i am not downvoting it but i reques you to give more information that is regarding the question. offcourse you answer provides relevant info but its very insgnificant to answer the whole quesiton

Comment: @rajendra "Telling" whether a language is recursive or not is not the same as "deciding" it. The first entails a mathematical proof; the latter implies there is a TM (i.e., an automated procedure) at work. And I never said such a problem would be decidable; what I did say was every recursive language (as a *language*) is decidable.

Comment: Also, it does not really make much sense to speak about TMs deciding properties of languages (directly). How are you supposed to model a language (with possibly *infinitely* many words) as a TM input anyway? What we *are* talking about here are the TMs which accept (or decide) these languages. Instead of a language $L$, you pass the description of a TM $M$ such that $L(M) = L$.

Comment: If you feel the answer can be improved, you can always suggest an edit using the appropriate functionality provided by the site.

Comment: i think then i am right here , not that you are wrong but the answer you tell tends to align to the reasoning that i had about decidablity , now it perfectely makes sense that REL are not decidable ( or semidecidable). but before wrapping it down could you tell me why the decidablility was described as such . it were good if decidability was a more general term that decide like in normal maths that conveys that " if an algorithm exists for a problem them its decidable else not".

Comment: @rajendra AFAIK the term "decidable" is derived from "decision problems" (which, in turn, is translated from the German "Entscheidungsproblem", probably first used in this sense by David Hilbert). Thus, "decidable" are those languages which correspond to valid decision problems. Actually, in CS, "decision" seems to be widely used strictly for algorithmic decisions. (This remark seems quite a detour from the original question, so I refrain from adding it to the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about the following two problems:

1. I give you a string and ask "Is it in this recursive language?"
2. I give you a language and ask "Is this language recursive?"

You're assuming that they're the same problem, but they're not.

Comment: yeah but i have reached my verdict that , the answer to problem1  is decidable and problem 2 is undecidable. am i right?